# Using GNU parallel on line based output without temporary files

Tags: gnu-parallel

The default output mode of GNU parallel is `--group`:
The output of each job is
written to a temporary file and passed to the output of `parallel` only after
the job has finished.

When using this default output mode on data larger than the `/tmp` space like in
`parallel lz4 -dc ::: /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 | wc`
it is slow and crashes with
`parallel: Error: Output is incomplete.`
`Cannot append to buffer file in /tmp.`

When using the `--ungroup` mode, lines are split in the middle which causes
a different output from
`parallel --ungroup lz4 -dc ::: /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 | wc`
than from unparallelized `lz4 -dmc /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 | wc`.

According to the `parallel` manpage, this should be solved by the
`--line-buffer` option as I understand it:
All jobs have an output pipe which is read by parallel and if output becomes
available from any job, it gets passed line by line to the output pipe of
the parallel process itself.
(Edit: I mean lines in blocks as is done for spreading large input to the parallel processes, not one syscall per line which would be far too slow.)

But this doesn't work:
`parallel --line-buffer lz4 -dc ::: /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 | wc -c`
results in the same disk full error as with the implied `--group` above.

How to use `parallel --line-buffer` without temporary files ?

System is LUbuntu 20 LTS. `parallel -V` returns `20161222`.
Comparision of raw serial and parallel decompression performance on Dual-Core i3-4130 with hyper threading (4 threads):

```
time ls -S /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 | parallel --ungroup lz4 -dc > /dev/null
1.461s
time lz4 -dmc /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 > /dev/null
3.069s
```

The real use case is as follows (workarond without `--line-buffer`):

```
time lz4 -dmc /var/lib/apt/lists/*Contents* | grep -F $'/parallel\t' | sort -u
usr/bin/parallel                                            universe/utils/moreutils,universe/utils/parallel
usr/bin/parallel                                            universe/utils/parallel
usr/lib/R/library/parallel/R/parallel                       universe/math/r-base-core
usr/lib/cups/backend/parallel                               net/cups-filters
usr/share/doc-base/parallel                                 universe/utils/parallel
real    0m5.349s
user    0m3.970s
sys     0m5.839s

time ls -S /var/lib/apt/lists/*Contents* | parallel lz4 -dc '{}' \| grep -F "\$'/parallel\t'" | sort -u
(same output as above)
real    0m3.669s
user    0m5.888s
sys     0m7.676s
```

This parallelizes not only the decompression but also the postprocessing and is the better solution here where the work is not 99 % in the first part of the pipe.
But this approach to parallelize the complete pipe is not always possible, so the general question remains open for cases where output of first step is not very small and thus streaming is wanted.

Comment: Are you sure the CPU would be the bottleneck? On my 12 year old 4 core 8 thread laptop with a fast SSD, `time printf '%s\0' /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 | xargs -r0 -n 1 -P8 lz4 -dc` (so even without the GNU parallel overhead) is not faster than `lz4 -dmc /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4` for me.

Comment: Did you consider the `--tmpdir` and/or `--compress` options?

Comment: @xhienne, the `--tmpdir` and `--compress` options imply using temporary files, which is what I asked to prevent in this question.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, added a comparision of raw serial and parallel decompression performance to the question.

Comment: @Juergen You are asking this question because your /tmp directory has not enough space for the temporary files created by parallel. I'm asking if you considered those options that were created to work around your issue.

Comment: @xhienne, sorry, but I was asking this question in order to maximize throughput. The general solution to this objective is to use streaming and prevent from using file I/O. Of course, the above is an artificial test case while the real task was more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you suggest, it would need the output of each `lz4` to go to separate pipes, and either a select/poll loop that reads from all and splits their output on lines or have one process / thread handling each pipe.

That sounds like significant overhead. Even without that overhead I find that on my 12 year old 4 core 8 thread laptop with a fast SSD, `printf '%s\0' /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 | xargs -r0 -n 1 -P8 lz4 -dc` (even without the GNU parallel overhead) is not faster than `lz4 -dmc /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4`.

Ideally here, you'd want for the parallelised command to output line-buffered in the first place. With many, you can do it with `stdbuf -oL`.

That doesn't seem to be the case of `lz4` though, but you could implement the second approach by hand (one process handling one `lz4` output) with:

```
printf '%s\0' /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 |
  stdbuf -oL xargs -r0 -n 1 -P4 sh -c 'lz4 -dc "$1" | paste' sh | 
  wc -c
```

(`paste` being a command that processes its input one line at a time and can be convinced to do line-buffering on output with `stdbuf`, see also GNU `grep`'s `grep --line-buffered '^'`; avoid `sed -u` which outputs one line at a time but also reads its input one byte at a time).

Even with the output discarded to `/dev/null`, on my system, that's 13 times as slow as the non-parallelised `lz4 -dmc /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4` (6.5s vs 0.5s).

And that's using `paste` that's written in C. GNU parallel being written in `perl`, if does support something like that internally, there's good chance it will be even less efficient.

Parallelising (at least in that fashion) would only make sense for CPU intensive tasks that produce relatively little text output which is the opposite of `lz4` which is meant to decompress with little effort.

Comment: In fact, this IS significant overhead. In my real case, the overhead is about 100 % but parallelizing with 4 threads gives more total throughput than the serial solution: Elapsed time with parallel is less than without when using one process handling each pipe as you suggest and what I did in my real word problem.

Comment: The parallel elapsed time is minimized when processing largest files first which is done by `ls -S /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4 | parallel ...` (or as you did with `... | xargs -P`). But this might not be helpful in your case where the number of threads is as large as the number of files (4 threads and 8 files for me, 1.1 GB compressed and 13 GB decompressed).

Answer (score 0):

The release notes for version 20170822 says:

- --line-buffer no longer uses tempfiles. This is faster and makes it
  possible for a single process to output more data than there is free
  disk space.

So the solution is to upgrade to 20170822.

GNU Parallel still uses temporary files for other stuff, but not for the line buffering.

It will also do The Right Thing if you have long lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

5gfile() {
    # Create file with 5GB long line
    perl -e '$a=(shift)x1000000;for(1..5000){print $a};print "\n"' $1 | lz4 > $1.lz4;
}
export -f 5gfile
parallel 5gfile ::: a b c d

echo The correct output: One line with a b c d
lz4 -dc {a..d}.lz4 | tr -s abcd

echo Output from parallel: One line with a b c d might be reordered
parallel --line-buffer lz4 -dc ::: {a..d}.lz4 |
    tr -s abcd

echo Output from xargs with stdbuf -oL
echo This does not handle long lines because stdbuf -oL does not guarantee only full lines will be written
printf '%s\0' /tmp/*lz4 |
    stdbuf -oL xargs -r0 -n 1 -P4 sh -c 'lz4 -dc "$1" | paste' sh |
    tr -s abcd
```